# How can I choose what statistical test to use?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

```
 Car   MPG
  1    28.0
  2    25.7
  3    25.8
  4    28.0
  5    28.5
  6    29.8
  7    30.2
  8    30.4
  9    26.9
 10    28.3
 11    29.8
 12    27.2
 13    26.7
 14    27.7
 15    29.5
 16    28.0
```

How can I answer this: The  vehicle  sticker  information  for  this  model  stated  a  city  average  of  30mpg.  Are  these  mpg  values  (Q3Mileage.Rdata)  consistent  with  the  vehicle  sticker?  What  type  of  statistical  test  do  you  choose  to  answer  the  question?  Perform  a  significance  test  using  the  0.05  significance  level  (alpha).    Be  sure  to  specify  the  hypotheses.  Provide  the  output,  the  test  statistic, and the  p-value.  Interpret  the  statistical  output  and  provide  the  answer  to  the  question  in  layman’s English.

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Exchange. Could you provide us with what you have already tried or what you know about the problem? The question as it is seems like a homework exercise.

Answer (score 6):

This is a question that is deeper than it appears.  Statistical tests create dichotomous thinking (especially when using a p-value cutoff) and when a test does not reject the null hypothesis you're left with [no information](https://www.bmj.com/content/311/7003/485).  I highly recommend using an appropriate confidence interval instead.  Confidence intervals are useful whether the null is rejected or now, and give you the appropriate caution when the sample size is not large enough to reject the null.

Two decent choices of confidence intervals in this situation would be the bootstrap-t confidence interval or the standard one-sample t-test type of interval.

Please tag your question as a homework question.

Comment: Answering "Which Confidence Interval Formula Should I Use" would probably improve this answer. :)

Comment: See the additions